# Fronted Gulp, SVG-Спрайты

Tags: svg, gulp, frontend, svg-спрайт

Настроил таск для спрайтов, но на выходе получаю один файл спрайта.

Можно ли разделить иконки по папкам и на выходе получать спрайты, каждый из которых соответствует своей папке? Создавать бандлы спрайтов(использую GULP, модуль gulp-svg-sprite)

```
gulp.task('svgSprite', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/svg/icons/*.svg') // svg files for sprite
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode: {
                stack: {
                    sprite: "../sprite.svg" //sprite file name
                }
            },
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/svg/'));
});
```

Спасибо

Comment: может несколько разных тасков?

Comment: Как вариант, но если нужно 20 бандлов то как быть? 20 тасков? Интересует есть ли динамическое решение?

Comment: это же javascript, сделайте цикл например